# Form factor and EFT form factors for an interaction of a WIMP and a nucleon

Tags: dark-matter

On the third paragraph(right column) of page 1 of the paper, http://journals.aps.org/prc/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevC.89.065501, it says, "Because the momentum transfer in the scattering is large compared to the inverse nuclear size, form factors are generally included ". I think this means if $\lambda = h / p \propto r$, then a form factor should be included, as the review of "Lewin and Smith" shown. Where $\lambda$ is the wavelength of an incident WIMP, $h$ is plank constant, $p$ is momentum transfer, $r$ is the radius of a nucleon.

**Q1:** Is my understanding correct? Beneath a little bit at same paragraph, it says "Once momentum transfers reach that point that $\vec{q}\cdot \vec{x}(i)$, where $\vec{x}(i)$ is the nucleon coordinate within the nucleus, is no longer small, not only form factors, but new operators arise."

The "new operators arise" under the condition of $\vec{q}\cdot \vec{x}(i)$ not being small, how small is it? My understanding is: since $h/p \propto x ~\Rightarrow p\cdot x \propto h$, so that is to say, if the $P\cdot x \propto h$ or $\vec{q}\cdot \vec{x}(i)\propto h$, then one needs to consider new operators, right?

**Q2:** If yes, then essentially, if one has considered a form factor, meanwhile, new EFT operators would arise (automatically), or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: The paper is behind a paywall. Sadly, there is no arXiv version...

Comment: @Martin, Thanks for you attention. There is an arXiv version, http://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.6288v1.pdf,  but the difference is not small. The corresponding content is the second paragraph of page 2.

Comment: Google Scholar didn't list any, but that's clear now that the paper is so dissimilar. But if there is a freely available version, always use that!

Comment: @Martin, you're absolutely right. Sorry for this miss. I thought any interested reader on this topic should be affiliated to an institution therefore has no any problem to access the website of PRC. Apparently, I was wrong, :-), sorry again.

Comment: It's absolutely no problem (welcome to StackExchange by the way). I have an affiliation, but I was always too lazy to create a VPN to the university and thus usually don't have access to such papers at home. That's how I noticed. Also, there actually are quite a few unaffiliated very interested and knowledgeable people around here.
Just to be clear: my comments were only meant as a suggestion to improve the question and an explanation of the suggestion, not as a reprimand, so there is no absolutely need for profuse appologies.